# How can I replace all instances of words with numbers in an R dataframe?

Tags: r

I am processing the results of a survey, and in order to analyse them statistically, I need to replace 'strongly agree', 'agree', 'neither agree nor disagree', 'disagree' and 'strongly disagree' with the numbers 5-1 respectively. In my data frame, each column is a question and each row is a respondent, so I need to replace every instance, not just within one column.

I apologise if this repeats a previous question - I have tried several answers, but without success, and I'm hoping to have this done by tomorrow morning for a meeting!

I did this:

`df[df=="Strongly Agree"]<-"5"`

But that replaced every 'Strongly Agree' with NA. I then tried this:

```
lookuptable <- data.frame(answers = c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither agree or disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"))

lookuptable$values <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

df[] <- lookuptable$values[match(df, lookuptable$answers)]
```

But this replaced all entries with NA!

I would be very grateful for any advice, I know I may be overcomplicating it because I'm fairly new to R! Thank you.

Comment: What is `df`.  Is it a data.frame with multiiple columns.  Note that `match` can take a matrix or vector as input and not a data.frame.  Probably, you need to change `match(as.matrix(df)` or `match(unlist(df), lookuptable$answers)`

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your quick response - I tried ```df[] <- lookuptable$values[match(unlist(df), lookuptable$answers)]``` but they're all still NAs, even the timestamp column which included none of the search terms

Comment: Based on the example I provided in the solution, it is working as intended.  I assumed that all the columns in the 'df' have those values specified in 'answers' column from lookuptable

Comment: Is there any chance that you have `factor` columns or are there any other columns other than the ones to compare

Comment: @akrun oh I see, thank you very much! I suppose I can just remove the timestamp column then?

Comment: what is the location of timestamp column.  If it is the first column, then just remove it with `df[-1] <- lookuptable$values[match(unlist(df[-1]), lookuptable$answers)]`

Comment: Oh cool, it is the first, thank you! That's useful. If I wanted to remove the first three columns, could I just use the same code but with -3?

Comment: Use `df[-(1:3)] <- lookuptable$values[match(as.matrix(df[-(1:3)]), 
        lookuptable$answers)]`

Comment: Also, note that this assignment should be done on the initial input data and not on the transformed one with NAs

Comment: You might have tried on the already assigned data which is of NA due to previous assignment with full columns.  Try on the initial input data

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we just need to change the `match(df` to `match(unlist(df)` or convert to `matrix` as according to `?match` , the first argument 'x' would be a vector

> x - vector or NULL: the values to be matched. Long vectors are supported.

`unlist`ing returns a vector or converting to `matrix` can be a vector with `dim` attributes

```
df[] <- lookuptable$values[match(as.matrix(df), lookuptable$answers)]
```

-output

```
 df
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   3  3  2  4  4  5  1  3  2   5
2   4  1  1  4  5  5  5  5  1   5
3   3  4  4  3  2  1  4  3  3   2
4   1  5  5  3  1  3  2  1  4   1
5   4  1  5  1  5  3  2  5  3   3
6   4  2  5  4  5  1  5  3  4   1
7   5  2  5  3  3  3  2  3  4   4
8   2  4  3  3  1  2  1  3  2   4
9   5  3  2  1  3  2  1  5  1   3
10  5  4  3  3  3  3  4  2  3   1
11  1  3  1  5  2  5  4  5  5   2
12  1  1  1  4  2  5  1  1  3   4
13  5  5  4  4  4  5  5  1  5   4
14  1  3  4  5  4  2  2  1  3   1
15  1  5  2  2  3  5  2  2  1   5
16  2  5  2  1  5  4  4  1  4   3
17  1  4  4  3  1  5  4  1  3   2
18  4  2  3  2  1  5  2  1  5   2
19  5  3  3  4  2  4  3  3  2   4
20  2  3  4  4  4  1  5  3  5   3
```

-compare the input data and lookuptable

```
> head(df)
                         V1                        V2                V3                        V4                V5                        V6
1 Neither agree or disagree Neither agree or disagree          Disagree                     Agree             Agree            Strongly Agree
2                     Agree         Strongly Disagree Strongly Disagree                     Agree    Strongly Agree            Strongly Agree
3 Neither agree or disagree                     Agree             Agree Neither agree or disagree          Disagree         Strongly Disagree
4         Strongly Disagree            Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree Neither agree or disagree Strongly Disagree Neither agree or disagree
5                     Agree         Strongly Disagree    Strongly Agree         Strongly Disagree    Strongly Agree Neither agree or disagree
6                     Agree                  Disagree    Strongly Agree                     Agree    Strongly Agree         Strongly Disagree
                 V7                        V8                        V9                       V10
1 Strongly Disagree Neither agree or disagree                  Disagree            Strongly Agree
2    Strongly Agree            Strongly Agree         Strongly Disagree            Strongly Agree
3             Agree Neither agree or disagree Neither agree or disagree                  Disagree
4          Disagree         Strongly Disagree                     Agree         Strongly Disagree
5          Disagree            Strongly Agree Neither agree or disagree Neither agree or disagree
6    Strongly Agree Neither agree or disagree                     Agree         Strongly Disagree
> lookuptable
                    answers values
1            Strongly Agree      5
2                     Agree      4
3 Neither agree or disagree      3
4                  Disagree      2
5         Strongly Disagree      1
```

---

Note: In the above solution, we assumed that the OP wanted to change all columns in 'df' based on the lookuptable.  If there is only a subset of columns that needs changes, select only the columns of interest (based on position index or by column name).  Suppose, if there is a column that is the first column we don't need to be included, use `-` before the index to select, do the transformation on the subset of data, and assign back to the same selected data columns

```
df[-1] <- lookuptable$values[match(as.matrix(df[-1]), lookuptable$answers)]
```

If there are multiple columns to be removed, use `c()` to append the index

```
df[-c(1, 5)] <- lookuptable$values[match(as.matrix(df[-c(1, 5)]), 
       lookuptable$answers)]
```

Or if we need to select without the first 3

```
df[-(1:3)] <- lookuptable$values[match(as.matrix(df[-(1:3)]), 
        lookuptable$answers)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(lookuptable$answers, 20 * 10, 
          replace = TRUE), 20, 10))
```